# How to display a currency other than the $ for data retrieved from a dataTable and using two decimal points?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, telerik

I have the following code:

```js
 //Assign Values to Labels in Table:
 TRANS_NB_LB.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["TRANS_NB"].ToString();
 TRANS_DATE_LB.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["TRANS_DATE"].ToString();
 TRANS_AMOUNT_LB.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["TRANS_AMOUNT"].ToString();
 SHIP_BILL_NUMBER_LB.Text = dt2.Rows[0]["SHIP_BILL_NUMBER"].ToString();
 SHIP_COST_LB.Text = dt2.Rows[0]["SHIP_COST"].ToString();
```

`TRANS_AMOUNT_LB` & `SHIP_COST_LB` are both `labels` containing amounts in SAR. How can I display their value with only two decimal points and SAR instead of $?
Am I supposed to store them in `int` variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var amount = double.Parse(dt1.Rows[0]["TRANS_AMOUNT"].ToString());
TRANS_AMOUNT_LB.Text = string.Format("{0} SAR", Math.Round(amount, 2));
```

Comment: It prompts me with a compilation error: 
The best overloaded method match for 'double.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: > TRANS_AMOUNT_LB.Text = string.Format("{0} SAR}", Math.Round(amount, 2));
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Ah yes, I added } at the end by mistake.

Comment: Thank you, but quick question if you may, what's the difference between declaring `amount` as `var ` and declaring it as `double`?

Comment: No difference, var is just shorter :) Compiler will replace it with double at compile time.